# How can I heal with my right hand in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When playing Skyrim, I can't equip anything to my right hand, no matter if I choose it with M1 or M2.

So say I want to have *Flames* on the left hand and *Healing* on the right, and I click on Flames, it's assigned to my left hand. Then I go to *Healing* and click on it with right hand it still assigns to my left one.

I heard that it's reversed, so you have to click with M2 for left hand and M1 for the right, but it still doesn't work.

How can I get *Healing* to be in my right hand?

Comment: Oh, and I just saw I can assign Healing to both, so LR, just not to the right hand only.

Comment: And for that matter I should mention I can't assign Flames to my right hand either, so that's not a possibility to solve that problem.

Comment: Welcome to gaming.SE! Please note that it's better to _edit_ your posts instead of adding details via comments

Answer (score 12):

Directly equip spells (same instructions whether in the magic menu, or the favorite menu).

- Left click on healing to equip it to the right hand (left mouse button).
- Right click on flames to equip it to the left hand (right mouse button).

Equipping spells via hotkey assignment

- Open the magic menu and press f on both flames and healing to mark them as favorites.
- Open the favorites menu and press 3 on flames and 4 on healing (3 and 4 for the example, any numbers, 1 to 8 will work).  This assigns the spell to the key, but not to any particular hand.
- exit the favorites menu.
- Press 4 once to equip healing to the left hand.
- Press 4 a second time to equip healing to the right hand.
- Press 3 once to equip flames to the left hand.

That is, press 4,4,3 to get the first spell in the right hand and the second spell in the left hand.

This also works to get a spell in the right hand and a shield in the left hand.

Answer (score 3):

It's a MAJOR flaw in the interface. The only way to get something else in your right hand is to equip a weapon in it then equip the spell you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, isn't there any patch out there to fix it?

Comment: Aparently, the only patch introduces even more bugs, like dragons flying backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by replacing my "Skyrim - Interface.bsa" file with a version that wasn't corrupted.

Comment: Where or how would you go about getting that file?

Comment: @fbueckert In a legit way? By verifying the cache in Steam. "Replacing" it with a non-corrupt one sounds... well, like they're not using Steam.

Answer (score -1):

all you have to do is switch the controls for the left and right mouse...

Comment: He's asking how to cast the right hand spell, not how to be able to equip any spell and cast it. -1